# String manipulation using MooTools / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mootools

How do I manipulate a string using MooTools / JavaScript

I would like to replace all after `/p/` in following url:

```
http://example.com/groups/browse/catId/14/p/1000-1500
```

Expected result:

```
 http://example.com/groups/browse/catId/14
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple enough with regex:

```
var url = "http://example.com/groups/browse/catId/14/p/1000-1500";

console.log(url.replace(/\/p\/.+/, ""));
//-> "http://example.com/groups/browse/catId/14"
```

In the regex above, `\/p\/` is `/p/` with escaped slashes, followed by `.+` which means *match any character (except white space) one or more times*.

You can brush up on your JavaScript regular expressions at http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html.

Answer (score 4):

That doesn't look like you want to *replace*, it looks like you want to *remove*.

You can do that with regular string operations in plain Javascript:

```
var s = "http://example.com/groups/browse/catId/14/p/1000-1500";

s = s.substr(0, s.indexOf("/p/")));
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to use mootools necessarily. you can split the string with `split` function from javascript

```
var myString = 'http://example.com/groups/browse/catId/14/p/1000-1500';
newString = myString.split('/p/');
alert(newString[0]);
```